# How to convert ORACLE date and timestamp types to string with timezone?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to convert ORACLE date and timestamp types into a string with timezone formated like this  `2020-12-31T21:00:00.000Z`?

Tried to search but unsuccessfully

Comment: hi, perhaps use [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) with the formal model you would like

Comment: Does the date/timestamp already represent a time in UTC, or do you need to adjust it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the date or timestamp already represents a time in UTC and doesn't need to be converted from another time zone, you just need `to_char`:

```
select to_char(timestamp '2020-12-31 21:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z")
from dual
```

```
2020-12-31T21:00:00.000Z
```

The `"T"` and `"Z"` are [character literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A).

If it's a date the `.000` part can be treated as a literal too, since dates don't have fractional seconds and `FF` isn't valid for a date:

```
select to_char(cast(timestamp '2020-12-31 21:00:00' as date), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS".000Z"')
from dual
```

```
2020-12-31T21:00:00.000Z
```

Or cast the date to a timestamp if you prefer.

If you do need to adjust the time zone then you can do that before converting to a string.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a6b8d6fc6c7e98c94176d63f1b3f0247)

Comment: And `.FF3` before `Z`